# Bringing an oscilloscope through the airport

Tags: oscilloscope

My university loaned us some oscilloscopes (Picoscope 2206B) to use in our free time. In a couple days I have to travel to my hometown for the holidays by plane. To make the most of my free time, I want to take the oscilloscope with me, meaning that I will have to carry it on the flight.

- Does it make more sense to put it in my bag, my carry-on baggage or my checked baggage?
- Is there anything I have to look out for?
- Will it create any problems when passing through security?
- Are there any chances that its functionality may be affected by X-rays?

I am aware that the question is rather silly and possibly even off-topic, but the oscilloscope is not mine and the last thing I want is to damage it.

Comment: There is the possibility that you have to open it to show you're not smuggling anything inside of it.

Comment: Treat it like a laptop.

Comment: As long your are not going to North Korea, I think everything should be OK.

Comment: I bought a scope abroad (US) and took it back home in the checked-in luggage. No questions were asked whatsoever.

Comment: carry-on baggage is at the mercy of the TSA goons, if they think the scope probes look like weapons you've got trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it make more sense to put it in my bag, my carry-on baggage or my checked baggage?

It's quite small (13 cm x 10.5 cm), so you can put it anywhere you want. However...

> Is there anything I have to look out for?

> Will it create any problems when passing through security?

When your bag(s) pass through x-ray the officers may notice it (especially if it has probes with it) so they may want you to open the bag and show the product and even explain its purpose. If you have a laptop I personally recommend you to keep the scope and its related parts in your laptop bag so that the officers think that those are part of your laptop and may ignore it during x-ray checks. Some officers are quite *sensitive* to some tools such as screw drivers. So, a small chance but the officers may treat the scope's probes as screwdrivers because of their shape :)

> Are there any chances that its functionality may be affected by X-rays?

Nope. At least, I don't think so. I took a Fluke battery-operated handheld scope and a Fluke battery-operated handheld power analyser with me to the airplane twice in the same day. Nothing happened.